# how many values can a custom dimension take in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, user-tracking

To anonymously analyze users flow and engagement I want to use the ClientID, as identifier of each user, as a value of a custom dimension. I have two questions regarding this idea:

- How many values can be associated to a custom dimension? This will determine the feasibility of this approach or not.
- Is there any other approach to track individually, yet anonymously, users activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a limit though for custom dimension length. But storing userId, sessionId customerId and timestamps for all hits in custom dimensions is not all that unusual these days. Here is a link to a post by Simo Ahava's post [Improve Data Collection With Four Custom Dimensions](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/) on how to set it all up in google tag manager.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Oren!

Answer (score 1):

For hit based custom dimension you can store as many values as there are hits. The problem is not storage, the problem is that the interface will not show more than 50 000 rows with distinct values (any additional value will go into a row labeled "other"). Also some of the reports (namely demographics) will not work with very small segments.

I cannot think of any other way to track users individually (and if you are interested in opinions, [I blogged about how I do not understand why people want to do this](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/a-river-runs-through-it-or-the-elusive-user-scope-in-google-analytics/)). The interface is not very well suited for this kind of "atomic" information, so I think the approach is more useful for API integrations that can properly visualize information on a per user basis.

Comment: if the dimension has a user scope then it would be more useful, wouldn't you think? Will this help for the demographics report?
Thanks for the reference on your post, I will def give it a read.

Comment: a user scope for client_id is wrong since cross-device access will associate many ClientID with one user and only the last will be kept. Use a session scope metric as ClientID persists across a session.

Comment: I said "hit based" because that is the theoretical maximum for the number of values in a custom dimension (a user scoped dimension can have as many distinct values as there are users). User scope will not help with demographic reports. This is a privacy concern so Google requires a minimum quantity of users before it displays the information (it is far-fetched but possible in a very small sample that you could identify a user by age, gender and location, so they nip this problem in the bud).